# Name that entity (2)

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I answer all who can connect
I amend mistakes without respect

I aim to place, I aim to serve
I give you knowledge with little reserve

In me, the primary colours I do hold
Though two had a child who won't grow old

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you:

> Google

?

I answer all who can connect

> Connect to the Internet

I amend mistakes without respect

> Suggestions!

I aim to place, I aim to serve

> A free service

I give you knowledge with little reserve

> An essential source of knowledge these days.

In me, the primary colours I do hold

> The logo is Blue, Red, Yellow (and Green) - NB: This refers to Subtractive Primary Colours (unlike those usually used in computer devices (Additive Colours))

Though two had a child who wont grow old

> Green is a child of Blue and Yellow

Comment: A note on the colors: [red, green, and blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color) are the (additive) primary colors, and the "child" spoken of is likely yellow (which is a mix of red and green). Green can be made by a mix of non-monochromatic blues and yellows, but when dealing with monochromatic additive light (as in computer monitors), it's red+green=yellow, not blue+yellow=green.

Comment: @TimS. I had no idea about that. Thank you. - I always knew primary colours to be RYB probably because of the context of natural colours - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color

Comment: I remember this one from ages ago, but just realised I'd never upvoted either the answer or the OPJ! Have a +1, both of you :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that here the subtractive primaries are meant.  The child who won't grow old is likely green, as 'green' is a synonym for 'young'.

Answer (score 1):

> The spellchecker on Microsoft Word

"In me, the primary colours I do hold":

The spellchecker uses three colors: green for grammar errors, red for spelling errors, and blue for miscellaneous others. These are considered by some to be the primary colors.

"I amend mistakes with little regret"

Haven't we all been annoyed when it automatically, incorrectly fixes "errors"?

Comment: Although this wasnt the intended answer, I believe this also to logically fit the clues and should be considered correct also. I did not know they used the primary colours although does it utilise yellow?

Answer (score 1):

> Google. It answers anyone who can connect to it, and it corrects anything that might be a mistake in your search terms. The logo contains the three primary colors, and a fourth color that is a mixture of two of them.

Answer (score 0):

It must be

> THE INTERNET

Only the part with the primary colors does not match perfectly.. I suppose, what is meant in this part are

> RGB pixels