# Oh how I lie - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.
But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.
I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.
If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.
Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.
A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,
And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

Hint 1:

> Look to my previous riddles for what type of clues might be found.

Hint 2:

> The riddle can be solved using only the first four lines.

Hint 2b; More of a guide of what to look at:

> Three different clues have been figured out by three different people.

Hint 3:

> Some punctuation might be misleading.

Hint 4:

> Look at the wording on line 4 very carefully.

Hint 5:

> There is no "c" in the answer. The third line does not hint towards a "c".

Hint 6:

> I think at this point, most of the clues have been figured out (at least all the major ones), just not all at once. Who can put the puzzle together?

Comment: At some point today, someone is going to post a fake puzzle that actually has no solution. I wonder if this is it :)

Comment: I should have done something like that today, but I didn't here.

Comment: I'm not sure why. I look at this riddle, and when I chant it on my head, the word "Google" pops up, but I'm not even sure where to start with those clues.

Comment: @ThalesPereira Try [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4498/5373) ;-)

Comment: @T.Sar I do that every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third attempt.

The Answer is

> **LION**

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.

> First letter of the word "liar" is L. As everybody suggested.

But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> "I" refers to actual word "I". So that means it is second letter of the word.

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> The third letter is "O", "Open" starts with O

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> Again, as everybody else related KNEE to "N". There will be a better explanation, I am sure.

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> Lion is surrounded by many Lioness and "Dame" is the female equivalent of the honour of knighthood, which means Lioness here.

A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,
And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

> May be it refers to the color of Lion which resembles to color of dust, again explanation can be better.

Comment: Got it! So, the deeper runnings of my mind: "Knee" sounds like it starts with "N," so you'd think it starts with "N". As for Dust, it wasn't a full clue, more for rhyming. My only really thought was that when a lion dies, they will turn to "dust." (Cue "Dust in the Wind")

Comment: Ahhhh.. Now I can concentrate on my work...

Answer (score 6):

Pretty sure the answer will be:

> April fool or April fool's day, though I haven't yet got all the clues

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.

> April fools jokes aren't true (liar), first here refers to the first if the month

But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> April fool's day started (allegedly) after new year's day moved to January first(?)

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> Reference to the "oo" in fool(?)

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> No idea....

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> People either love or hate April fool's day. And there's lots of pranks that day.

A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,
And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

> Need to answer while it's still April fool's day

Comment: what do you mean by "April fool's day started (allegedly) after new year's day moved to January first(?)"

Comment: Some good thoughts, but sadly no. You are getting close with one of the clues.

Comment: @Richard - Apparently the new year was celebrated in the last week of March up to the 16th century, and when it was moved, people made fun of those who still celebrated the old date.

Answer (score 4):

Building off of NonsenseSynapse and rand al'thor, I'm going to guess

> KICK

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.
But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> You thought the first letter was 'i', but it's the second

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> 'See' -> 'C'. Taken literally, we need to open the word "open" and take what we see visually: Half of 'O' is 'C'.

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> 'Knee' starts with 'K'. In addition, kicks are used to start fights, and they begin at the knee

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,

> Shoes are sometimes called kicks, and boys often judge each other by how cool or lame their shoes are.

You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> Not sure, but "surrounded by many o" could reference soccer balls?

A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,

And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

> Well, at the end of a kick the foot returns to the ground, or "dust"

Additional evidence:

> In comments you indicated that the answers "LICE", "LOCK", and "LINK" each have 2 correct hints, which is how I got "_ICK". In response to NonsenseSynapse you said "the end will match the beginning" so I put the last letter first.

Comment: I like it, so definitely +1, but not quite. My comment to Nonsense meant the end clues will match what you find in the beginning.  Without giving too much away, you have one of the clues right. Lock has two right, but perhaps not in the right order.

Comment: By the power of teamwork we shall conquer this riddle!

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> LICE

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.

> first letter of "liar" is **L**

But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> Second letter  is **I**

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> see == **C**

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> "a knee" == "an **E**"

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.
A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,
And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

> Not entirely sure about these lines, but I went off of your clue that the riddle can be solved in only the first 4 lines. I think there's something important about "surround by many 'o" being something surrounded by the letter **O**, but I haven't figured out its importance yet.

Comment: Very good thoughts. Not quite though. You are right on for two of the clues. You'll see the end will match the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the answer may be :

> A Girl-Friend

You call me a liar, and say I was the first :

> We tend to say to our girl friend , that are the first love or first time(Sex)

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see :

> They tend to open up and express what they feel and see.

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> When ever in fight, they may tend to use their knee(Probably hit the groin area with the knee)

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> Whether they are cool or lame, they ll be surrounded with dame - Dame is the female equivalent of the honor of knighthood in the British honors system (According to Wiki)

And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust :

> Probably turn to dust may mean, that they ll simply leave off eventually if we don't value them

I know this may probably be wrong and weird,But seems funny and kind of relevant if you think about it. :)

Comment: Definitely worth a try, but all of the clues are needed to get the answer. Well, at least more clues. Check hint two.

Comment: @AggieKidd I Have edited the answer, Though i feel it may be wrong..but thought i would share. :)

Comment: +1. I like it. Very nice. Not what I was going for, but very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Along similar lines to Khan's answer (though I hadn't seen that when I had this idea), how about

> a LOCK?

First four lines are letterplay, as suggested by the hints.

*You call me a liar, and say I was the first.*

> First letter of the word "liar" is **L**.

*But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.*

> I'm not sure about this line, but...

*I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.*

> "See" is a homophone of **C**; the reference to opening also goes with the lock idea.

*If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.*

> The first letter of the word "knee" is **K**.

*Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,*

> "Cool" backwards is almost "lock". Not sure about "lame".

*You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.*

> Could be a reference to the Num Lock, Caps Lock, Scroll Lock keys on a computer (though I realise this is a bit of a stretch).

*A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,

 And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.*

> There are both wordplay and metaphorical clues in the riddle above.

Comment: +1 - Getting a lot closer. You are correct on two of the clues. Look at a few of the lines a little more closely though. I made this one a bit tricky.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Satan

because

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.

> Most people think Satan was the first liar

But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> Some people say that God was the first liar because he said “But as for the tree of the knowledge of good and bad you must not eat from it, for in the day you eat from it you will positively die,” but then neither Adam nor Eve dies THAT DAY. However, I am no believer, but I still understood it to mean that on that day, their state would be changed from "never going to die" to "will now eventually die".

http://www.jehovahswitnessblog.com/watchtower-lies/who-was-the-first-liar-in-the-bible/

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> The devil, in a sense, by offering them the forbidden fruit, opened the eyes of Adam and Eve to be able to recognize good and evil. The Devil said, "For God knows that in the day you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil."

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> Since Satan was in the form of a serpent, maybe it means that he will strike at your knee, or any part of your lower leg?

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> This seems to fit Eve more than Satan. I guess Eve will be around other ladies, who would also be her daughters and nieces

A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,
And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

> This also seems like it would refer to Adam or Eve, not Satan. Part of God's punishment of Adam and Eve was, "By the sweat of your brow you will eat your food until you return to the ground, since from it you were taken; for dust you are and to dust you will return.

Comment: Some very good thoughts. +1. Not what I was going for though. Notice "A couple types of clues." There are two types of clues in the riddle. See if you can determine which is which.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is

> SIN

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.

> Lying is a SIN

But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> Here "I" refers to actual word "I". So that means it is second letter of the word.

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> Cannot really make any sense of this in regard to my answer

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> A SIN makes you weak and you feel "WEAK" at the knees

Just tried to focus on first four lines as you hinted.

**EDIT..**

I guess the 3rd Letter is

> "O" [I'll open, open]

I am guessing the word is

> LION

but I am not quite sure as I cannot relate to few clues.

Comment: +1 - You got one clue right for sure. See if you can figure out the others and then tie that into the last couple of lines as well.

Comment: You've got it. Almost all of the clues are hints for letters, but  5-6 are a liters clue. See if you can figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

Second try:

> LINK.

*You call me a liar, and say I was the first.*

> As before, the first letter of the word "liar" is **L**.

*But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.*

> **I** is the second letter (credit to Deepak for this idea).

*I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.*

> If you click a link on a webpage, it opens to a new page and you see new information. (Possibly this line also gives the letter **L**.)

*If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.*

> As before, the first letter of the word "knee" is **K**.

*Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,*

> When someone provides you with a link to a webpage, you may think it either cool or lame.

*You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.*

> Many links in a chain.

*A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,*

> As before, there are both wordplay and metaphorical clues in the riddle above.

*And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.*

> I'm pretty sure there's some kind of religious or mythological reference to chains crumbling to dust, but I can't bring the exact quote to mind.

Comment: +1 - Getting even closer. You are now correct on 2 clues. Look closely at a couple of the lines and I think you'll see where you aren't quite on. But definately a great explaination!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

> Silk

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.
But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> The letter I is the second, not the first. The first is S, similar of snake, the liar of Eva and Adam.

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> A reference to Allen key, similar to letter L

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> It suggests a K

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> It's a fabric used to make clothes, ladies love it!

Comment: I like it, but not quite. Check out hint 4. Love the Allen wrench thought, but not quite either. For that line check hint 3.

Answer (score 1):

I could be way off but is it a

> `Mirror`?

`You call me a liar, and say I was the first:`

> What we see in the mirror is not real. It's only a reflection of reality.
> (A mirror is an object that reflects light in such a way that, for incident light in some range of wavelengths, the reflected light preserves many or most of the detailed physical characteristics of the original light.)

`But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed:`

> It's the second form of reality. Another thought was that mirrors are not the only ones reflecting. The first reflector is Water. Later came the mirrors. Water is not cursed but few Mirrors are believed to be cursed.

`I'll open, open, and tell you what I see:`

> "Looking glass" is another term for a Mirror.

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee:

> I can't really connect this & the mirror. But there's a website called mirror which is for soccer/football. So, 'fight' could mean 'match'. 'Start with a knee' could mean 'kick'.

`Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame, You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame:`

> Women love mirrors, any mirror will work... whether it's a good mirror or a lame one.

`And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust:`

> Before it's covered by dust or broken by falling on the ground (dust).

Comment: Make sure to use spoiler tags for your explanations">!"

Comment: I put in the spoiler tags.

Comment: Some good thoughts, but a few are a bit of a stretch. Not quite what I was going for. If you check other answers, you may get a glimpse of where things are going.

Answer (score 0):

Few additional answers, mostly based on what has already been said. *If one is correct, I'll edit this post and make it look better.*

**Option #1:**

> Mien (meaning aspect).

Because:

> You call **M**E a liar. ME is the pronounce of the Greek letter Mi. **I** was the second. "Open, open, see" may refer to **E**. Knee is pronounced as **N**I, another Greek letter. Also, mien can be cool or "lame", and ladies pay attention to it.

**Option #2**:

> Milk

Because:

> M and I as said above, L as in the other answer, K because of knee. Also, milk is extracted by females (dames) and some don't like its taste.

**Option #3:**

> Sign

Because:

> S, I and N are explained in other answers, the G letter is hard to explain.

**Option #4:**

> Lien

Because:

> The letters are all explained in the other answers.

**Option #5**:

> Nips

Because:

> I start with a Knee (N), second letter is I. P and S aren't easy to justify.

Most of these are garbage, I know, but they're attempts. If none of these is correct, I give up ahah!

Comment: Close on some. Right one for one that no one has gotten yet.

Comment: I've edited with some more attempts, my last!

Comment: So very close. To try and keep you in it, Here are some fractions;  
1: 2/4;  
2: 1/4 (kind of 2, but mostly 1);  
3: 2/4;  
4: 2/4;  
5: 1/4 (closer to 2, but out of place) ;

Answer (score 0):

**SECOND ATTEMPT**

I think I got it..

The answer is

> **CION**

You call me a liar, and say I was the first.

> A quick search reveals that CION means a descendant or offspring, esp. of an illustrious family. So its a first child.

But I was the second, the first liar isn't cursed.

> As explained before, here "I" refers to actual word "I". So that means it is second letter of the word.

I'll open, open, and tell you what I see.

> The third letter is "O", "Open" starts with O

If I start to fight, you'd think I start with a knee.

> As everybody else related KNEE to "N". There will be a better explanation, I am sure.

Whether you think I'm cool, or whether I be lame,
You'll often find me surrounded by many o' my dame.

> The first offspring is often surrounded with relatives.

A couple types of clues, riddle now you must,
And tell me what I am, before I turn to dust.

> Cannot connect this.. :D

Comment: Shoot. I gave a bad comment. You've got all but the first letter.

Comment: Nopes. I had actually posted this answer before you commented..